# Venn diagram with multiple events

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$65$ kids at a school voted for their favorite ice-cream flavor. They can vote for up $2$ flavors and the choices are vanilla,chocolate,and strawberry. $10$ kids voted for strawberry, $35$ voted for vanilla,and $25$ people voted for chocolate. Let $A$ be the amount of kids that voted for only vanilla, $C$ be the amount people that voted for chocolate,and $B$ be the amount of people who voted for both.What is $\dfrac{ab}{c}$?

I set up equations and got $\begin{cases}S + B_1+B_3 = 10 \\ V+B_1+B_2 = 35 \\ C= 25 \end{cases}$. It seems hard to solve for $\dfrac{ab}{c} = \dfrac{V*B_1}{25}$

Comment: Please define your variables

Comment: The B's are just the intersections of any two sets $S,V,C$.

Comment: Is $C$ the amount that voted *only* for chocolate?

Comment: No, although this question may have an error in it. If it is solvable with that constraint then you must be correct.

Comment: Actually, I meant the $C$ in the problem statement, not the $C$ in your equations.  Do you see the confusion? :)

Comment: Ah, good point. I fixed that now.

Comment: Does anyone know?